# apt-get issue with BeagleBoneBlack and Debian 8

Tags: debian, apt-get, beaglebone

When updating my BeagleBone Black running Debian 8, I get this here:

```
root@bbb-one:~# apt-get update
Hit http://security.debian.org jessie/updates InRelease
Hit http://repos.rcn-ee.com jessie InRelease
Ign http://ftp.us.debian.org jessie InRelease
Get:1 http://security.debian.org jessie/updates/main armhf Packages [802 kB]
Hit http://ftp.us.debian.org jessie-updates InRelease
Get:2 http://repos.rcn-ee.com jessie/main armhf Packages [1013 kB]
Hit http://ftp.us.debian.org jessie Release.gpg
Hit http://ftp.us.debian.org jessie Release
Get:3 http://security.debian.org jessie/updates/contrib armhf Packages [994 B]
Get:4 http://security.debian.org jessie/updates/non-free armhf Packages [4416 B]
Get:5 http://ftp.us.debian.org jessie/main armhf Packages [8898 kB]
Get:6 http://ftp.us.debian.org jessie/contrib armhf Packages [44.3 kB]
Get:7 http://ftp.us.debian.org jessie/non-free armhf Packages [74.9 kB]
Fetched 10.8 MB in 18s (581 kB/s)
W: Failed to fetch http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/dists/jessie-updates/InRelease  Unable to find expected entry 'main/binary-armhf/Packages' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

sources.list shows:

```
root@bbb-one:~# cat /etc/apt/sources.list
deb http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ jessie main contrib non-free
#deb-src http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ jessie main contrib non-free

deb http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ jessie-updates main contrib non-free
#deb-src http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ jessie-updates main contrib non-free

deb http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates main contrib non-free
#deb-src http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates main contrib non-free

#deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian jessie-backports main contrib non-free
##deb-src http://ftp.debian.org/debian jessie-backports main contrib non-free

#Kernel source (repos.rcn-ee.com) : https://github.com/RobertCNelson/linux-stable-rcn-ee
#
#git clone https://github.com/RobertCNelson/linux-stable-rcn-ee
#cd ./linux-stable-rcn-ee
#git checkout `uname -r` -b tmp
#
deb [arch=armhf] http://repos.rcn-ee.com/debian/ jessie main
#deb-src [arch=armhf] http://repos.rcn-ee.com/debian/ jessie main
```

It's in an operational environment, hence I cannot test a lot.

What do the W: and E: messages mean and how do I get rid of them?

I have no clue how to handle this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jessie-updates has been archived and is no longer available on default mirrors.

See: https://lists.debian.org/debian-devel-announce/2019/03/msg00006.html

You should remove these lines from your sources.list:

```
deb http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ jessie-updates main contrib non-free
#deb-src http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ jessie-updates main contrib non-free
```

Then run `apt-get update` again.

If you wish to look for outstanding updates from this specific repo, you need to switch to archive.debian.org

First install debian-archive-keyring

```
apt-get install debian-archive-keyring
```

and then replace these above lines to:

```
deb http://archive.debian.org/debian/ jessie-updates main contrib non-free
#deb-src http://archive.debian.org/debian/ jessie-updates main contrib non-free
```

However archived repos are no longer supported and will not recieve any further updates.

Jessie will become EOL next year, so you should start thinking about upgrading it to stretch.

Comment: Great. Thanks a lot. Answered my question 100% and more!